# ffmpeg is not executing clip.run() when compiled with pyinstaller

Tags: windows, python-3.x, ffmpeg, pyinstaller

When executing the .exe file in another machine that doens't have it's requeriments installed, running the programs gives the error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
  File "threading.py", line 864, in run
  File "y2m.py", line 80, in workit
  File "site-packages\ffmpeg\_run.py", line 202, in run
  File "subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__
  File "subprocess.py", line 992, in _execute_child
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I'm compiling the exe file using the command:

```
pyinstaller y2m.py
```

I've been reading every other post in this and others forums refered to this kind of problem but I don't seem to find or understand the way of fixing this.

The source code is in [here](https://github.com/thriskel/y2m/blob/master/y2m.py)

and the warny2m.txt file is in [here](https://github.com/thriskel/y2m/blob/master/warny2m.txt)

Things that I have tried:

- using --paths=pathToLibFolder
- using -w
- using an older pyinstaller version
- adding python3 to path
- using -p DIR to add C:\Python3\Lib location then sub locations, also individual scripts. (those 3 ways to see if it would work)

EDIT:

When using ffmpeg\_run.py the code fails. line is `clip.run()` where clip presents the input and output file.